# AttributeError at /accounts/signup/ 'Person' object has no attribute 'META'

Tags: python, django

When I try to sign up a new user, the page returns an AttributeError, as shown here:

[image]

I am using a custom model, and here is my models.py and forms.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class Person(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

and

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from .models import Person

# Create your forms here.
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

Finally, here's my views.py for the accounts app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate

from .forms import SignUpForm

# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(user)
            return redirect('lists:index')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        context = {
            "form": form
        }
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context)

def login(request):
    context = {

    }
    return render(request, "accounts/login.html", context)
```

How do I fix this? It seems like the error has something to do with the login() function in my views.py, but I don't see why. For good measure, here's the part of my setting.py that shows my AUTH_USER_MODEL:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Person'
```

Answer (score 2):

do not use `class Meta:` in your `SignUpForm` only include define the field which you want to use like:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(
                               attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                      'name': 'password', 'id': 'password',
                                      'type': 'password', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    # similarly other fields like username, password1 and password2
```

you are about to use meta field for `ModelForm`

Comment: Okay so only the fields I specify in the SignUpForm will get displayed? If that's the case, how would I go about doing the username, password1 and password2 fields, just so I'm sure about it?

Comment: I didn't mean that you can access those field but to apply common style or custom css you need to include it in your form otherwise template will render default style for those field

Comment: Okay so I have to explicitly make the form in HTML, instead of just doing form.as_p. That's okay, but my question was how should I create username, password1, and password2 fields in my SignUpForm class, in the same way that I have the email = forms.EmailField(). Should I do something like username = forms.CharField(), or is there a better way?

Comment: @ShivBhatia check updated code; I have included sample for password where you can create a widget with html attributes of your choice